# Как вывести текст из БД?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Допустим у меня есть БД text в ней таблица text в ней id и text
Мне нужнго вывести text в тег

```
<p>text</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала подключитесь к БД:

```
<?php 
try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=Название хоста (у вас наверняка localhost);dbname=название БД','имя пользователя','пароль');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
 ?>
```

Потом сделайте запрос на выборку данных из таблицы:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('select * from text');
```

Далее в цикле (если у вас несколько строк записей) выводите следующим образом:

```
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
  while($res = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
    echo '<p>'.$res['text'].'<p>';
  }
}
```

Если хотите вывести 1 запись:

```
$res= $stmt->fetch();
echo '<p>'.$res['text'];.'</p>';
```

Можно это делать прямо в html, тогда просто не забывайте вставлять теги php.
Например:

```
<p><?php echo $res['text']; ?></p>
```